# Delete Children rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-tree

I have the class project ,

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :Users
  acts_as_tree
end
```

I want to delete all children, if I delete the parent, in this case meaning, if I delete the project(parent) must be deleted all users (children) and subprojects(children).

I can add by user `dependent: :delete_all` but I don't know how can I do with acts_as_tree

Thanks

Comment: You should probably define the tree relationship as an associaion as well! `has_many :children, class_name: 'Project', dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "parent_id"` (check the name of the foreign_key)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dependent: :destroy like:-

```
has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
```

Comment: I know how I do for users, I don't  know how can I do this for acts_as_tree!
read the issue plz

Answer (score 0):

`act_as_tree` default behavior will automatically destroy the `children` when you destroy the `parent` as you can see in the source code (https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree/blob/master/lib/acts_as_tree.rb)

However, you can change this behavior the exact same way as you would with the `has_many` method, for instance :

```
act_as_tree dependent: :delete_all
```

So in your case, you just need to cascade destroy the users :

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  acts_as_tree # dependent: :destroy
end
```

Therefore @user3506853's answer is actually correct considering the way you present your issue.

Cheers !